# How does a diode work?

Tags: diodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly does a diode do?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52437/what-exactly-does-a-diode-do)

What happens in a diode to make current only flow one way around a circuit? My physics teacher said it was something to do with the metals in it and the impurities in them. Can anyone give me a detailed explanation. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Some demonstration of basic research would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably better off asked on the physics stack, but essentially:

You have two differently [doped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_%28semiconductor%29) semiconductors, one P-type and one N-type. The N-type has excess electrons, and the P-type has excess "holes" (which means the absence of an electron in an electron shell)

When you bring the P and N type materials together, you form a [P-N junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-n_junction). At the junction, some of the excess electrons cross over and fill the holes in the P-type material, forming a depletion zone (essentially a built in potential):

[image: Depletion zone]

This depletion zone is (almost) non-conductive, as it has no free charge carriers. Now if we apply a potential (voltage) across the junction, depending on the polarity, the depletion zone either widens or narrows. If the region widens, the non-conductive region increases and no current can flow through the diode.

[image: Widening zone]

If it narrows, at a certain potential (~0.7V for a silicon diode) the diode will begin to conduct. This (hopefully) explains why the diode acts in the way it does.

[image: Narrowing zone]

Above images from this [introduction to diodes](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/212_fall2003.web.dir/Marvin_Casanova/physics.htm).

Also, this image (from the Wikipedia P-N Junction link above) shows the P-N junction with a little more information than the above images:

[image: Wiki P-N Junction]