# When current flows why diode not makes any shortage in it

Tags: diodes

I konw that a diode works like the explained here.

[How does a diode work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/how-does-a-diode-work)

but I have different question as I am not expert in Electronics,
well i am showing you a very simple circuit which is below.
[image]

if you see this (i am sorry i am not expert) there are 2 wires going out from the source of power 1 is going to diode and 2nd is going to capacitor,
normally when we touch plus and minus there will be some shortage but in this circuit (at red circle) I can guess that it should be short circuit but i know i am wrong.
so what is the logic here please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: You have to realize, that current flows in loops.

Comment: i want the answer that how does current flows so i can understand it please explain #Dzarda

Comment: The title of this question does not reflect the body of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that are not necessarily correct and it depends on what you mean.

> there are 2 wires going out from the source of power 1 is going to diode and 2nd is going to capacitor

One node is usually considered to be a reference node. All voltages are with respect to that node. This is usually indicated with a ground symbol, however, you're schematic does not have one, so it's implied that the the bottom of Vs is considered to be the reference node. However, its not necessary for that node to be the reference node, it just makes it easier to analyse the circuit.

> normally when we touch plus and minus

If you connect a piece of wire or some very small impedance then you have a short. Otherwise its not a short. So if you use a meter to measure the voltage, it's not a short because the voltmeter will have a high impedance.

The title of your question does not reflect the body of the question, so I have only described the points you mentioned in the body of your question.

**added based on comments**

It's best not to describe a signal as plus and minus, because those terms are used to indicate polarity. Instead begin using the term source (the origin of the signal).

A capacitor is a has an impedance that is dependent on frequency.

$$ Z_c = \frac{1}{j\omega C} $$

As frequency, \$\omega \$, increases, Zc will decrease. So at high enough frequencies the capacitor will look like a short. If this is from a text book, you can pretty safely assume that the capacitor's impedance is not zero when given schematics such as this. However, if you really want to be sure, you need to get some values, what is C, and what is the frequency of your source.

Comment: my main question is that if we remove capacitor than I can understand that plus and minus is provided to load which is usual but when we put the Capacitor in circuit why its not shorting?

Comment: @Andriopak Because a capacitor is not just a piece of wire.

Comment: @Andriopak: Actually a capacitor is more like an open circuit, not a short circuit. Thats why it blocks DC.

Comment: what will happen if we put plus and minus on both sides of a diode? farward biased??

Comment: @Andriopak I added some additional information in my answer. However, you are now beginning to divert away from your original question, and you should create a new question for that.

Comment: well you are right i am beginner and still don't understand how does the electricity flows from these devices, thank you for your help

Comment: i have researched and understood this basic circuit kindly tell me last thing that does capacitor have any negative and positive terminals?

Comment: @Andriopak if you mean polarized, then some caps do have a fixed polarity (which means that that one terminal has to be  + and the other has to be -). Other types of caps do not, and can be placed in anyway.

Comment: is there anyway to check that which capacitor have fixed polarity and which don't?

Comment: @Andriopak http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_2.html