# Logical to physical implementation of voltage regualtor decoupling capacitors

Tags: capacitor, pcb, voltage-regulator

For this typical LM7805 application :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcBfLI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Due to bad planing when placing my components on the PCB (perfboard) I ended in the following phisical implementation :

So basically, on the rail of the 7805 input I've got in the order : VCC+, 7805-IN, Capacitor.

Will this have any impact ?
(I think not, but would like to be sure)

**EDIT :**

My question wasn't very clear and the schematic was more confusing than hepling.
What can be the impact of having VCC+,7805-IN,Capacitor+ instead of having VCC+, Capacitor+, 7805-IN

[image]

With Red as VCC, Green as 7805-In, Orange as C1.

The top strip is what I'm asking.

The bottom strip is the "ideal one".

Comment: You're much better off bodging the capacitor in than having it across the board like that.

Comment: What? Rather than removing the schematic, why don't you add the right one? Now it's even more unclear what you are asking.

Comment: A photo of the actual circuit would probably be the best way to show the physical layout.

Comment: @PhilFrost : Hey give me sec ;) I was adding a schematic of the physical pinout to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. It's not going to make any difference because the distance from the 7805 VIN pin to the capacitor pin is the same in both cases. For cases like this (bulk capacitance placement), even if the distance did change, by up to a few mm, it would probably not make a noticeable difference.

Comment: What's with the micro-femto-Farads?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, ho I inserted the f but the online schematic editor looks like adding it anyway... Don't take the f in account, it's micro farad.

Comment: Olin isn't being very forthcoming with the explanation for what you obviously intended to do. \$f\$ is femto-, or the metric prefix for \$10^{-15}\$. \$F\$ is [Farad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad), something *entirely different*.

Comment: You can't put something in the schematic, then tell people, in comments no less, to not take it into account.  The point of my comment was to get you to FIX THE SCHEMATIC, not instead compound the error by telling people to read something other than what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are missing C2. Without this, the regulator's transient response will be diminished. It may also be unstable. Check the datasheet.

Otherwise, it doesn't matter if you put C1 on the left or the right. It's just important that it's close to the `IN` and `GND` pins. From your picture, it looks like it is.

For many circuits you can assume that any changes in voltage or current happen everywhere instantly, because the rate at which the changes propagate as waves is so fast relative to the length of the things in which they are propagating. This is called the [lumped element model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model). This is why it doesn't matter on which side of the regulator C1 is placed: even though when the input voltage changes, this propagates as a wave at the speed of light which really will "see" the regulator first, some *extremely small* time later that wave will see the capacitor, and send another wave back at the regulator, and very quickly an equilibrium will be reached. See also [How does the current know how much to flow, before having seen the resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/19759/17608)

Comment: My question wasn't clear. I've edited it.

Comment: I just don't talk about C2 as it's not in the scope of the question. For C2 I'm able to place it "on the correct side" of the regulator. But C2 is included. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever "order" you think the input cap relative to the regulator input pin is irrelevant.  The important point is that the cap provide a good low impedance path for the right frequencies.  It can't do that if it's too far away, counting both the power and ground connections, since the wires add series inductance which increases impedance.

It's hard to say what kind of caps you have exactly, since micro-femto Farads makes no sense at all.  If you meant µF, then 100 is too big since that will likely be electrolytic.  Electrolytic caps have poor high frequency performance, so the regulator may not be stable.  It is fine to have a 100 µF electrolytic cap on the input, but parallel it with a 1-10 µF ceramic to get the low impedance at high frequencies.  The same logic applies to the output cap.  A 10 µF ceramic on the output will work fine with a 7805 regulator.

Comment: microfemtofarads makes perfect sense: it's a zeptofarad. :)

Comment: No to be confused with Zeppo Farad, one of the lesser known brothers of the Farad Brothers comedy troupe, popular in the early years of the last century. :) :)

Answer (score -3):

It will work just fine. You don't need to change anything at all. The good old 7805 is very stable and not fussy at all about input and output capacitors.

Putting space of an inch or two either way will not cause an LM78xx regulator to oscillate or otherwise misbehave, but it may make your circuit last years longer. Too many designs try to minimize the distance and butt an aluminum electrolytic up close to a regulator dissipating significant heat.

Note that this advice is based on a lot of production experience and many designs, however it does not apply to regulators other than the 78xx. The 79xx negative regulators, and most LDO regulators are very sensitive to (especially) the output capacitor. The frequency compensation (which is what guarantees stability) changes when you change the output capacitor.

In particular, sticking a ceramic capacitor onto some older LDO regulators (which may not even warn of the problem in the data sheet) can cause oscillation. ALWAYS be careful when substituting ceramic for an aluminum or tantalum capacitor (you can tell by the polarity marking in the data sheet schematic). Even some very-low-ESR aluminum caps could cause problems.

Comment: I've seen 78xx regulators go into high frequency oscillation when used without sufficient capacitance on the input and output.

Comment: Agreed. Most linear regulators can be made into perfectly fine oscillators without consideration to decoupling and layout. Shunt regulators too. (TL431, etc.)

Comment: I have never seen a 7805 go into oscillation with any reasonable (which the OP's configuration certainly counts as). I have even tried to make them oscillate with various combinations and several feet of wire. That's based on more than 100,000 products shipped, with regulators from several manufacturers. I posted a challenge to show one oscillating with no winner.

Comment: LDOs and shunt regulators are different beasts. They can easily be made unstable with too little, too much or capacitance with too low or too high ESR. I recently debugged another person's design where they used ceramic capacitors on the output of an LDO. It oscillated under the wrong (temperature and load) conditions. I fixed it by adding 1 ohm of series resistance, making it like a tantalum or aluminum electrolytic.