# What happens if the there is a mismatch in impedance between signal generator and BNC cable?

Tags: impedance-matching, bnc

My signal generator has 600 ohms in its internal output impedance (Picoscope 3204B). The BNC cable at my hand is 50 ohms, so is there any problem with the impedance mismatch? If yes how can I workaround that?

Comment: What's the signal frequency?

Comment: One easy way would be to use a 600:50 transformer.  Ferrite is preferred, for size and speed reasons.

Comment: The signal freq range is between DC and 1MHz

Comment: The wavelength of a 1 MHz signal traveling in the polyethylene dielectric of the coax is about 200 m.

Comment: @davidmneedham, so if I understand you correctly it will be an issue in the signal integrity if I employ an RG-58 cable with 24" length

Comment: A rule of thumb is that you don't need to consider transmission line effects when the length of your transmission line is less than 1/10th the length of the wavelength of the signal. So for a coax less than a meter long and a frequency of 1 MHz, I wouldn't worry about impedance matching of the coax. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143541/impedance-of-waveguides-shorter-than-1-10-of-wavelength

Comment: 1 MHz maximum frequency, but 1 MHz sine wave or 1 MHz square wave? The square wave contains much higher frequencies than the sine wave.

Comment: @Justme, I agree with you. 1MHz for any standard signal including square waveform.